# need to push data to threads in perl

Tags: multithreading, perl

I am trying to create a multithreaded program which has threads executing jobs and the data is pushed using a shared variable

how can I push data from main thread to the child threads

This sample script here gives me an error "Invalid value for shared scalar at thread_test line 10."

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use threads;
use threads::shared;

my %thread_data :shared = ();
my @anon :shared = ('a','b');


push @{$thread_data{1}} , \@anon; #This does not work
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to initialize `$thread_data{1}` as shared array reference before pushing into it,

```
$thread_data{1} = shared_clone([]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that. Use `Thread::Queue` instead.

```
 use Thread::Queue;

 my $work_q = Thread::Queue -> new();

 my $thr = threads -> create ( \&thread_that_does_stuff );

 $work_q -> enqueue ( \@anon ); 
 $work_q -> end();

 $thr -> join(); 

 sub thread_that_does_stuff {
   while ( my $thing = $work_q -> dequeue ) {
   print join ( ":", @$thing );
   }
 }
```

`Thread::Queue` is a FIFO queue that lets you pass data around threads without worrying (much!) about locking semantics.